# Accessing file from SFTP without downloading it to local using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp

I currently have the following configuration:

```
    @Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpHost);
    factory.setPort(sftpPort);
    factory.setUser(sftpUser);
    if (null != sftpPrivateKey) {
        factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
    } else {
        factory.setPassword(sftpPassword);
    }
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    // fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectory);
    fileSynchronizer
            .setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(sftpRemoteDirectoryFilter));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "0/5 * * * * *"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
            sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpLocalDirectory));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
public MessageHandler resultFileHandler() {
    return message -> System.err.println(message.getPayload());
}
```

This one downloads anything from the remote directory to a local directory. But I have a rest controller and I would like to stream back a byte array of the file from the SFTP server instead of downloading it to a local machine. Is it possible in Spring Integration/Boot? Do you have some code examples, please?

Comment: It would be good to have a routine like `Stream getFile(final String path);` which does fetch from remote

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you have a REST controller to make requests for SFTP files, then I would recommend to look into an `SftpOutboundGateway`, which indeed designed for requests and replies. See its `Command.GET` and `Option.STREAM`:

```
    /**
     * (-stream) Streaming 'get' (returns InputStream); user must call {@link Session#close()}.
     */
    STREAM("-stream"),
```

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#using-the-get-command

Not sure what led you to `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` for your request-reply task...

Comment: Tbh I have been struggling to find any complete example to download a file from SFTP server. The only one what I found is this one which uses that `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`.

Many thanks for the doc! So I need something similar like the following:
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new SftpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "'my_remote_dir/'");
    }

But after it how can I read a specific file in my rest controller?

Comment: Do you have a mini github project or anything which might be useful, please?

Comment: There is this one, but it is XML-based: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/sftp. I'm not sure why is the question about controller. I guess you got a file name in the request, so you just send a `Message` with that file name into the input channel of that service activator. You probably are missing the `setRemoteDirectoryExpression()` for the remote dir. And that `expression` in the ctor must be like a `payload`. Just because your request message payload is going to be a remote file name to perform a GET command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FtpClient` and call `retrieveFileStream` to read a file from the remote sftp server.  See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream-java.lang.String-

Comment: So you would recommend not to use Spring in order to complete this?

Comment: For the use case you described, i don't see any value being added by using spring integration.  Spring Integration uses FTPClient under the hood.  FTPClient has a retrieveFile method that will write directly to an OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using [`RemoteFileTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rft)